# shouldperformseguewithidentifier WatchKit extension

Tags: ios, segue, watchkit

Is there such a method called "shouldperformseguewithidentifier" in WatchKit extension or something similar to that one? It is because i need to check before I push to another view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014957-CH1-SW27) for `WKInterfaceController` shows no such method.

If you implement your navigation programatically – that is, without using segues – you can use whatever logic you like to determine when a push to another interface controller happens. You can use `pushControllerWithName:context:`, for example.